# Missing required parameters for route (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am getting totally frustrated now...

Trying to use an edit method within a controller. All the other controllers work fine, but here I might have missed something and could not find.

Error:

```
 Missing required parameters for [Route: blocked.edit] [URI: 
remittance/blocked/{blocked}/edit]. (View: 
/var/www/xxxxxxxx/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: 
/var/www/xxxxxxxx/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

Here is my controller method:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $blocked = $this->model->find($id);
    return view('remittance::edit', compact('blocked'));
}
```

Route to this method:

```
remittance/blocked/{blocked}/edit | blocked.edit | Modules\Remittance\Http\Controllers\RemittanceController@edit
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('remittance/blocked', 'RemittanceController', [
  'except' => ['show']
]);
```

I am calling this method from DataTables, whenever I click edit I am directed to url:

```
 http://localhost/remittance/blocked/xxxx/edit
```

Snippet from DataTables class where it is rendered:

```
addColumn('action', function ($query) {
     return view('partials.actions.delete', [
        'actions' => ['edit'],
        'route'   => $this->model,
        'object'  => $query
        ]);
     })
```

Which is correct for the routes. 
I checked other similar topics to this one, but all of them were caused because of missing {parameter}.

Comment: can you show you `route`

Comment: Is this `view('remittance::edit', ...` correct? should be `view('remittance.edit', ...`

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta added a route

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta yes, I am using HMVC and my components are in module hierarchy

Comment: run in your teminal and show the result `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Your laravel version?

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta there is a snippet already listed from the command mentioned in your comment, unless you need full list of routes.

Comment: @SandOfVega 5.4.36

Comment: Show the line in your view where you're calling `blocked.edit`

Comment: can't help you until you show terminal data of route

Comment: @aynber edited post

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta  `GET|HEAD  | remittance/blocked/{blocked}/edit           | blocked.edit                 | Modules\Remittance\Http\Controllers\RemittanceController@edit`

Comment: you have not shown where you are calling a URL helper to generate a URL to that route .. that is where the error is ... go into that layout and look for `blocked.edit` and see why you are not passing any parameters with it when generating that URL

Comment: @lagbox the problem is that layout.app is just a basic header, sidebar loader, that load basic components for all the views.

Comment: alright, good luck :)

Comment: @lagbox actually you were right, added an answer, how it was fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a problem with breadcrumbs. I have registered a route there and did not pass the required parameters. Totally forgot, that layout.app was loading breadcrumbs.

Now:

```
Breadcrumbs::register('blocked.edit', function ($breadcrumbs, $blocked) {
$breadcrumbs->parent('blocked.index');
$breadcrumbs->push(trans('remittance::titles.edit'), route('blocked.edit', compact('blocked')));
```

});

Was before:

```
Breadcrumbs::register('blocked.edit', function ($breadcrumbs) {
$breadcrumbs->parent('home');
$breadcrumbs->push(trans('remittance::titles.edit'), route('blocked.edit'));
```

});

Thank You everyone for help :)

Answer (score 0):

use this  maybe help you

```
public function edit(Blocked $blocked)
{
     $blocked = $blocked;
     return view('remittance::edit', compact('blocked'));
}
```

if not work then let me know

Comment: I was using parameter blocked before, but as that one was not working, tried changing to the one, mentioned in the problem.

Comment: code updated check and let me know if its not working

Comment: Still the same. Yes, actually my entity is called Blocked :D

Comment: can you share the screenshot what error you are getting

Comment: what is `remittance`

Comment: @ArūnasKiršis `what is remittance`

Comment: a sum of money sent in payment or as a gift.

Comment: is this a model...?

Comment: It is not exactly an action if you are referring to it, but I believe it is going a bit off topic. And no it is not a model. It is a module used by this name.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the parameter in the route should be same with the parameter in the method.
So if, the uri markup is `remittance/blocked/{blocked}/edit`, it must be `public function edit($blocked){...`

Comment: Still the same (was using like that before)